# fill_between() in barplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# define corner points
x=['a','b','c','d','e']
y=[12,10,5,1,4]
plt.bar(x,y,color='lightgray')
plt.fill_between(x,3,alpha=0.3,color='r')
```

[image]

I'd like to fill the empty space using `fill_between()` as shown in the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `axhspan` to have a horizontal bar over the complete plot width. Use `zorder` to have it behind the bars.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
y = [12, 10, 5, 1, 4]
plt.bar(x, y, color='lightgray')
plt.axhspan(0, 3, alpha=0.3, color='r', zorder=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: Note that the call to `fill_between` in the post doesn't fill between the bars. It converts the x-values to numeric (being `0, 1, 2, ...` for a categorical axis) and uses a default `y2=0`. So, internally equal to:

```py
plt.fill_between(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y1=3, y2=0, ...)
```